# Is there a way to get the count for the number of tests in a jasmine describe block?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

Is there any way to get the number of tests in a jasmine describe block? I am trying to get the number of tests in a describe block to make sure we have tests for all the pubic interface points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can actually modify the tests yourself and you're not trying to find them completely from the outside.....

Just use `this`!

```
describe("Testing Suite", function(){

   var numOfTests = this.children.size;
   console.log(numOfTests);

    it("should do something", function(){
       //do something
    })

    it("should do something", function(){
      //do something else
    })
})
```

Here, `numOfTests` gets the children(tests) of the block, and obviously calling `.size` of it will get the number of tests.

Comment: I am going to accept this I was doing it another way which I will post below but I believe yours to be better.

Comment: Great, thank you! I can't wait to see what your solution is.

Comment: also one thing of note is that the call to `var methodsCount = this.children().length` should be at the bottom after the method definitions.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of listing more ways to accomplish this I will post my own method for accessing the count of the tests inside the describe block.

```
var publicAPI = describe('Public  Interface', function () {

    /* Methods */
    it('should expose/define a initialize method', function () {
        expect(controller.initialize).toBeDefined();
    });
});

console.log(publicAPI.specs_.length); //this is the count
```